# Style markers in strings

Tags: output-formatting, string-manipulation

I'm dealing with strings in *Mathematica* and I would love to handle their stylling in the most cenvenient way.

Without loss of generality, let's assume I want to make some parts of string `Bold`.

Example of desired output:

> to **be** or **not** to be

I know I can achieve that by for example:

```
StringForm["to `` or `` to be", ##] & @@ (Style[#, Bold]& /@ {"be", "not"})
```

but I want single function `bold` and some kind of markers (here `#`):

```
bold @ "to #be# or #not# to be"
```

> to **be** or **not** to be

---

It is **my approach**:

```
bold = Module[{x}, 
              With[{patt = "#" ~~ x : Except["#"] .. ~~ "#"},
       StringForm @@ ({
                      StringReplace[#, patt :> "``"],
                      Sequence @@ StringCases[#, patt :> Style[x, Bold]]
                      })]
             ] &
```

and I have **couple of questions** about it:

- do you feel that `#` is not the best choice too?  :)
- is this: `{patt = "#"~~...}` a proper way of storing patterns?
- maybe some other ideas?

I like this way but I'm not sure if it is bulletproof. It is quite handy because `StringCases` etc do not look for overlaps by default.

Notice that *mixed-style-string-form* tends to produce some kind of error If you want to edit that cell. This is also what I to want to ask about:

> ```
> INTERNAL SELF-TEST ERROR: MathEditCells2|c|1384
> Click here to find out if this problem is known, and to help improve
> Mathematica by reporting it to Wolfram Research
> ```

Comment: Is the question about style markers in strings or on the choice of # or about patterns? As for #, why invent new styles when it is easier to use something commonly used, such as `**bold**` in markdown?

Comment: @rm-rf it is a question about implementation/creating such function in *Mathematica* so one do not need to use `Row` or `StringForm` each time. If there are markers in MMA like "\ n " then it is a question about them.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26640/4999

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `#` or any other marker for your personal use, but for general purposes, I prefer sticking to the Markdown scheme that we're all familiar with, and is used in several other places. With the `styleMarkdown` function defined later in this answer, we can do something like this:

```
styleMarkdown["The **quick** brown fox *jumps* over the ***lazy*** dog."]
```

[image]

Here's the code for the above function:

```
ClearAll@styleMarkdown
styleMarkdown[str_String] := Module[{style, applyRules},
    style[s_String, {weight_ : Plain, slant_ : Plain}] := StringJoin[
        "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"", s, "\", FontWeight -> ", ToString@weight,
        ", FontSlant -> " , ToString@slant, "]\)"];

    applyRules[s_String, rules_] := 
        StringReplace[s, # ~~ Shortest@x__ ~~ # :> style[x, #2] & @@@ rules];

    applyRules[str, {"***" -> {Bold, Italic}, "**" -> {Bold}, "*" -> {Plain, Italic}}]
]
```

The function only handles **bold**, *italic* and ***bolditalic***, but you can extend it to other styles, if you want. The limitations in markdown also apply here. For example, with `****foo****`, is it to be interpreted as (markers in `[]` and styled text in `<>`) `*[***<foo>***]*` or `[***<*foo>***]*` or `*[***<foo*>***]`, and so on.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be more stable.