# Stylesheet modifications mimicking Stack Exchange styles

Tags: stylesheet, customization

I find myself frequently highlighting and formatting portions of text cells in a *Mathematica* notebook.  Bold and Italic typesetting is easy to handle but I would like to use `backticks` to provide formatting similar to the SE editor or perhaps use underscores and asterisks to auto-format in other ways (say for example, text within ** here ** would be red and text within _ here _ would be highlighted yellow.

Is it possible to customize a stylesheet to afford this type of formatting?

Comment: [This answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29378/5) has a simple markdown bold/italic/bolditalic -> mma converter. A simple solution would be to have a button that, when pressed, reads all the text cells in the current notebook and applies this function on the contents. You can extend this with other rules.