# Strings with exclamation marks in Mathematica

Tags: output-formatting, string-manipulation

Given this input

```
FullForm[ToString[TraditionalForm[x]]]
```

*Mathematica* outputs

```
"\!\(TraditionalForm\`x\)"
```

It seems like `\!` at the beginning of the string indicates that the following is to be interpreted as an expression. But this can't be quite right, because

```
"\!\(Minus\`x\)"
```

displays as simply `x`, rather than `-x`.

How should the escape characters `\!`, `\(`, `` \` ``, `\)` be understood?

Comment: ok, this is what you need to know: [tutorial/StringRepresentationOfBoxes](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/StringRepresentationOfBoxes.html)

Comment: why this is always so hard to find those tutorials... (*I really mean it, I'm struggling with it.*)

Comment: Thanks, @Kuba. That's exactly what I was looking for. (Searching for `\!` on Google and in the documentation brought up nothing relevant.)

Comment: Yes, it's quite tough to search for ? ! etc ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to edit the title and answer this question as wiki because I think it is not easy for new users to find this kind of information. The more if they are not aware of special handling of ? ! in search fields.

So the explanation of things like:

> ```
> \!\(TraditionalForm\` c (1 + x)\)
> ```

is in the tutorial [String Representation of Boxes](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/StringRepresentationOfBoxes.html).

---

Here are related topics on SE:

- [SE' markdown type in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29373/5478)
- [Converting string representation of boxes into explicit boxes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47213/5478)